# Bash script - How to know a program has terminated

Tags: bash

I have created a script that compiles and then executes 4 .c programs.

Now, my script is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Compiling first program. . ."
gcc -o first first.c
echo "File compiled."
echo

echo "Compiling second program. . ."
gcc -o second second.c
echo "File compiled."
echo

echo "Compiling third program. . ."
gcc -o third third.c
echo "File compiled."
echo

echo "Compiling fourth program. . ."
gcc -o fourth fourth.c
echo "File compiled."
echo

./first
./second
./third
./fourth
```

Every executable file needs to run alone.
The question is: launching the execs in that way, will they be executed simultaneously? How do I know when a program has terminated before launching the following one?

Comment: Your example lanunches them in a sequence. So, every proram will run after the previous finished. (unless the programs forks itself). For the parallel execution you need send them to the background (using `&`) or by using `gnu parallel` or `xargs -P` and such...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each command in a Bash script will complete before the next one starts, unless you specifically use a feature that does otherwise, such as `&`:

```
foo bar &                # starts `foo bar` to run "in the background"
                         # while the script proceeds
```

or `|`:

```
foo | bar                # runs `foo` and `bar` in parallel, with output
                         # from `foo` fed as input into `bar. (This is
                         # called a "pipeline", and is a very important
                         # concept for using Bash and similar shells.)
```

That said, this doesn't mean that the command completed *successfully*. In your case, some of your `gcc` commands might fail, and yet the other programs would still be run. That's probably not what you want. I'd suggest adding something like `|| { echo "Command failed." >&2 ; exit 1 ; }` to each of your commands, so that if they fail (meaning: if they return an exit status other than `0`), your script will print an error-message and exit. For example:

```
gcc -o first first.c || { echo "Compilation failed." >&2 ; exit 1 ; }
```

and:

```
./second || { echo "Second program failed." >&2 ; exit 1 ; }
```

(You can also put this sort of logic in a "function", but that's probably a lesson for another day!)

I recommend reading through a Bash tutorial, by the way, and/or [the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), to get a better handle on shell scripting.